# Trying to create a program that inserts a 0 between each integer in an array provided by a user

Tags: c

**Thank you everyone that commented and helped me, it is now working properly!**

This is the first program I've ever attempted to write so please bear with my limited knowledge of how C works. So I'm trying to create a small program for class that will insert a 0 between each value in an array. The parameters of the project are the user must define the size of the array, integers for the array, double the size of the array, then have a function called insert0 place a 0 between each value of the given array. We must create a main function and another function called insert0 that will be called in the main function.

In the insert0 function we are required to have the parameters n, a1, a2. N being the size of the array, a1 being the user given array, and a2 being the array that contains the input of a1 with a 0 inserted between each value. So example: n = 3, user inputs 1 2 3, output should be 1 0 2 0 3 0.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to put the 0's between each value. I haven't had many examples of how a proper program should be written and have only been shown very basic if/else and for loops. The few things I've tried have resulted in almost what I need but not quite. This is what I have written right now. It is a very rough draft that is not very proper as I've been trying to experiment with ways to just get it to output what I want, so please excuse the sloppiness.

**Code removed**

As it is right now it almost works, but I know it's not correct. Right now using the inputs I said previously with n=3 and 123, it outputs 1 0 3 0 0 0. I know why it doesn't work but I just can't come up with a way to correct it. I've been working on it for almost a week, changing small things here and there but I just can't think of a way. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance for any constructive criticism for the program overall.

Comment: It would be better to dynamically allocated your array and then extend it as more numbers are added.

Comment: Can you use a debugger like gdb to step through your program to see exactly where the program is not doing what you want it to? (Hint: in insert0)

Comment: @ThomasF I've never used a debugger before but thank you for the suggestion I will most certainly look into that for the future. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: if you have N values, and then insert a zero _between_ every two values, then you need 2*N-1 total values, not 2*N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the values of `a2` in the second loop of `insert0()` , change the arithmetic (note that you can do it in a single loop):

```
void insert0(int n, int a1[], int a2[])
{ 
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a2[i * 2] = a1[i];
        a2[i * 2 + 1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Also note that it is preferable to use dynamic memory (in order to avoid buffer overflows) when you don't know the number of elements beforehand:

```
int *a1 = malloc(sizeof *a1 * n);
int *a2 = malloc(sizeof *a2 * n * 2);
if (a1 == NULL || a2 == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
...
free(a1);
free(a2);
```

Comment: I never even though of combining multiplication and addition. I tried both separately and couldn't get it. Thank you so much for the help. It is very appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the additional edit about dynamic memory. Someone had mentioned that as well so I appreciate showing me how it should be implemented.

Comment: You are welcome :), avoid as possible the use of VLA's, especially when it depends on an user input.